# Hover zoom effect with multiple images but with only 1 result output

Tags: html, css

Hover zoom effect with multiple images but with only 1 result output

example:

> https://codepen.io/wavyblues/pen/LYLWNMy

Code:

```
<div class="img-zoom-container">
  <img id="myimage" src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/google-logo-png/google-logo-png-suite-everything-you-need-know-about-google-newest-0.png" width="300" height="240">
    <img id="myimage" src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/google-logo-png/google-logo-png-suite-everything-you-need-know-about-google-newest-0.png" width="300" height="240">
  <img id="myimage" src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/google-logo-png/google-logo-png-suite-everything-you-need-know-about-google-newest-0.png" width="300" height="240">

  <div id="myresult" class="img-zoom-result"></div>
</div>
```

Scripts:

```
function imageZoom(imgID, resultID) {
  var img, lens, result, cx, cy;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  result = document.getElementById(resultID);
  /*create lens:*/
  lens = document.createElement("DIV");
  lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
  /*insert lens:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
  /*calculate the ratio between result DIV and lens:*/
  cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
  cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
  /*set background properties for the result DIV:*/
  result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  result.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";
  /*execute a function when someone moves the cursor over the image, or the lens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  lens.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
  function moveLens(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    /*calculate the position of the lens:*/
    x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
    y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
    /*prevent the lens from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;}
    if (x < 0) {x = 0;}
    if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;}
    if (y < 0) {y = 0;}
    /*set the position of the lens:*/
    lens.style.left = x + "px";
    lens.style.top = y + "px";
    /*display what the lens "sees":*/
    result.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
  }
  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
  }
}


imageZoom("myimage", "myresult");
```

what i wanted to do :
when i point to second image the 'image-zoom' effect works with 'myResult'

the ways that i think off is that create multiple div but it would be redundant

Comment: Your images all have the same ID. This is wrong. IDs have to be unique.

Comment: Did you write that JS code? If so, it seems like it should be relatively simple to add more than one image. If not, I would definitely recommend getting a good understanding of any code you copy from the internet before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Give your images different `ID` and then call the function like this:

```
imageZoom("myimage", "myresult");
imageZoom("myimage1", "myresult");
imageZoom("myimage2", "myresult");
```

Answer (score 0):

Give unique ID to each `img` element.

```
<img id="myimage0" src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/google-logo-png/google-logo-png-suite-everything-you-need-know-about-google-newest-0.png" width="300" height="240">
<img id="myimage1" src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/google-logo-png/google-logo-png-suite-everything-you-need-know-about-google-newest-0.png" width="300" height="240">
```

Function calls:

```
imageZoom("myimage0", "myresult");
imageZoom("myimage1", "myresult");
```

Since there are multiple images, We have to first identify on which one we are hovering the mouse pointer. For that we do the following, First we extract the Id of the image on which we are hovering and pass it to the `imageZoom` function along with `myresult`.

```
$('img').mouseover(function() {
    var imageId = this.id;
    imageZoom(imageId, "myresult");
});
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/wavyblues/pen/LYLWNMy

tried the ways but everytime it will the 'last' image for the result

Comment: Please remove the for loop, Instead of that use the above function. I have edited the answer. This should work fine.